# snmp-check not sending output via 1> to a .txt file

Tags: snmp

In Kali, running

`snmp-check <IP target> -c public 1> OP.txt`

does NOT place the output in the file

but

`snmp-check <IP target> -c public`

writes to the terminal.

Why is this happening and how can I get an output file from this tool?

Comment: This is not an information security question, but a general Linux software (and specifically output redirection) question. It should be asked on [su] or on [unix.se].

Comment: Maybe it writes to stderr. Have you tried `2>` instead of `1>`?